# How to change category page layout 4 columns to 3 columns - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

How to change the Category page's layout from 4 columns to 3 columns?

Comment: You mean you have to display product in 3 column?

Comment: Yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: I don't think that `4 columns` layout is  available at magento,So you have create own layout?

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can achieve this using CSS, you can set layout with based on your requirement.

> Cureent CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1024px), print
.page-products .products-grid .product-item {
   margin-left: calc((100% - 4 * 24.439%) / 3);
   padding: 0;
   width: 24.439%;
}
```

> To replace with below

```
@media (min-width: 1024px), print
.page-products .products-grid .product-item {
   margin-left: calc((100% - 4 * 24.439%) / 3);
   padding: 0;
   width: 32.333333%;
}
```

**Note :** Adjust with based on your layout.

Comment: Thanks but I knew this already, is there any other option with .xml file ?

Comment: May be other way is possible but this is a easiest way.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to this link below:

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-number-of-columns-in-category-listing.html

Comment: that article is for Magento 1 not Magento 2